# mongodb how to query sum string?

Tags: mongodb

I have some data in `order` document like:

```
{ "_id": "...", "orderTotal": { "amount" : "10.99", "unit": "USD"}, "orderTime": "...", ... }
{ "_id": "...", "orderTotal": { "amount" : "9.99", "unit": "USD"}, "orderTime": "...",  ... }
{ "_id": "...", "orderTotal": { "amount" : "8.99", "unit": "USD"}, "orderTime": "...",  ... }
```

I want to query the orderTotal of all orders group by day:

```
db.getCollection('order').aggregate([
  {
    '$group' : {
        '_id': { day: { $dayOfMonth: "$orderTime"}, month: {$month: "$orderTime"}, year: { $year: "$orderTime" }},
        'totalAmount': { $sum: '$itemTotal.amount' },
        'count': { $sum: 1 }
    }
  }
])
```

but got:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "day" : 12,
        "month" : 12,
        "year" : 2016
    },
    "totalAmount" : 0,
    "count" : 4607.0
}
```

the `amount` is a string. Use `parseFloat` but got NaN.

```
db.getCollection('order').aggregate([
  {
    '$group' : {
        '_id': { day: { $dayOfMonth: "$orderTime"}, month: {$month: "$orderTime"}, year: { $year: "$orderTime" }},
        'totalAmount': { $sum: parseFloat('$itemTotal.amount') },
        'count': { $sum: 1 }
    }
  }
])
```

got

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "day" : 12,
        "month" : 12,
        "year" : 2016
    },
    "totalAmount" : NaN,
    "count" : 4607.0
}
```

I can't update the `order` document to change `itemTotal.amount` to float like other questions said:

```
db.order.find().forEach(function(data) {
    db.order.update({
        "_id": data._id,
        "itemTotal.amount": data.itemTotal.amount
    }, {
        "$set": {
            "itemTotal.amount": parseFloat(data.itemTotal.amount)
        }
    });
})
```

I have no permissions to do this.
So, how can I get the sum by day?

Answer (score 13):

This is not possible as of MongoDB 3.4. This feature has already been requested, but hasn't been implemented yet:

[Need a type conversion mechanism to convert between strings and numbers](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-11400)

So the only way to solve your problem is to manually perform the totalAmount sum in javascript...

---

## Edit

This is now possible in **MongoDB 4.0** wich introduced operator to convert from one type to another, for example **`$toDouble`**

so the query would be:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "totalAmount": {
        "$sum": {
          "$toDouble": "$orderTotal.amount"
        }
      },
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

you can try it here: [mongoplayground.net/p/4zJTPU912Es](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4zJTPU912Es)

Comment: @heramerom any finding with mogodb version 3.6 ??

Comment: @SourabhBhutani 

As a work around in 3.6, you could consider using a collation with numericOrdering: true for that particular issue. See the docs for collation

Hope that helps.