# Sum all document with mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sum, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with three documents:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5bfe572882ace71e43703d15"), "event" : "Cdr", "privilege" : "cdr,all", "accountcode" : "", "source" : "22000", "destination" : "98723546", "destinationcontext" : "from-internal", "callerid" : "\"22000\" <22000>", "channel" : "SIP/22000-00000005", "destinationchannel" : "SIP/9144502101-00000006", "lastapplication" : "Dial", "lastdata" : "SIP/9144502101/98723546,300,Tb(func-apply-sipheaders^s^1)", "starttime" : "2018-11-28 15:51:47", "answertime" : "", "endtime" : "2018-11-28 15:51:52", "duration" : "5", "billableseconds" : "0", "disposition" : "NO ANSWER", "amaflags" : "DOCUMENTATION", "uniqueid" : "1543395107.5", "userfield" : "" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5bfe5829b3a9321f241f10f2"), "event" : "Cdr", "privilege" : "cdr,all", "accountcode" : "", "source" : "98723546", "destination" : "s", "destinationcontext" : "ivr-1", "callerid" : "\"98723546\" <98723546>", "channel" : "SIP/9144502101-00000007", "destinationchannel" : "", "lastapplication" : "BackGround", "lastdata" : "custom/int1", "starttime" : "2018-11-28 15:56:03", "answertime" : "2018-11-28 15:56:03", "endtime" : "2018-11-28 15:56:09", "duration" : "6", "billableseconds" : "6", "disposition" : "ANSWERED", "amaflags" : "DOCUMENTATION", "uniqueid" : "1543395363.7", "userfield" : "" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5bfe5833b3a9321f241f10f4"), "event" : "Cdr", "privilege" : "cdr,all", "accountcode" : "", "source" : "98723546", "destination" : "22000", "destinationcontext" : "from-did-direct", "callerid" : "\"98723546\" <98723546>", "channel" : "SIP/9144502101-00000008", "destinationchannel" : "SIP/22000-00000009", "lastapplication" : "Dial", "lastdata" : "SIP/22000,,HhtrIb(func-apply-sipheaders^s^1)", "starttime" : "2018-11-28 15:56:12", "answertime" : "2018-11-28 15:56:12", "endtime" : "2018-11-28 15:56:19", "duration" : "7", "billableseconds" : "7", "disposition" : "NO ANSWER", "amaflags" : "DOCUMENTATION", "uniqueid" : "1543395372.8", "userfield" : "" }
```

I want to sum $duration and try command:

```
db.cdrs.aggregate([{$group: { _id: "$event", total: { $sum: "$duration"}}}])
```

Result return:

```
{ "_id" : "Cdr", "total" : 0 }
```

How to use $sum return result Sum duration of three documents(5 + 6 + 7 = 18)?

Comment: your query is ok. Your duration data type is string i think. please check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `sum` `duration` by converting `string` to `Int`

> Its work on  Mongo `version 4.0`

Example :

```
db.getCollection('A').aggregate([{
    $addFields: {
      convertedDuration: { $toInt: "$duration" },
   } },
   {
    $group: { _id: "$event", total: { $sum: "$convertedDuration"} } 
   }
])
```

reference Link : [link1](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toInt/), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41119461/mongodb-how-to-query-sum-string)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fXv2483bte7) is the working example of your query, click on **run** at the top. In your Documents, the duration is stored as **String**, I guess mongoDB won't convert and sum the values, please change your duration to Number while storing. Your query is fine.